# Мобильный браузер неверно отображает сайт в версии для пк

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, мобильная-разработка

Я по заказу создал сайт.
Работает на всех основных браузерах на всех устройствах и расширениях экрана.

Проблема следующая.
На устройствах на андройд, например, нередко можно встретить мобильный браузер.
Этот браузер не совсем верно отображает мобильную версию и очень плохо версию для пк на мобильном устройстве.
С одной стороны, в википедии, например, указано, что этот браузер ограничен в функциональности, но все же, являясь дефолтным, может ли он оказать существенное воздействие на восприятие сайта, я не знаю.

Тот, кто заказал сайт требует исправления. А я не знаю, как вообще с этим быть.

Спасибо за ответы! Они слишком замечательны, чтобы я мог сказать, что кто-то ответил лучше. Огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Да как быть - если дефолтное не срабатывает, то поставьте переключение по юзер-агенту на работающий вариант - стили для именно этого случая.

Список браузер-агентов мобильного браузера (List of mobile browser User-Agent strings) https://deviceatlas.com/blog/mobile-browser-user-agent-strings

Создание собственного решения для обнаружения устройств (Building your own device detection solution) https://deviceatlas.com/blog/building-your-own-device-detection-solution

Comment: https://kirkizh.ru/2018/03/request-desktop-site/
Только я там юзер-агент поставил на норм-версию для мобил
Срабатывает на всех, кроме этой с*

Comment: И, да, их дофига, этих браузеров. Каждый под свою мобилу. Первый абзац вики
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Yevgeniy, там во второй ссылке вариант маски вообще для андроид, без разницы версия - или посмотрите, что там отдает тестовый для заказчика - тогда уже можно сориентироваться будет, думается. Иного варианта нет - нужно как-то его выделять и отдавать по его возможностям.

Answer (score 1):

не вдавался в подробности, но я так понимаю он не поддерживает html5 или css3. единственные способы выйти из ситуации - либо поменять версию языка для всего сайта, что сделает его отсталым в скорейшем времени, либо нанимать бэкэндера и заморачиваться с определением браузера и подмене версий языков фротенда в скрипте. в таком случае либо требуйте с него плату за бэкенд, либо говорите, что сам себе роет яму поддержки сайта через пару лет.